# Optimization of parallelepiped inside an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, volume

Let $K \in R^3$  the ellipsoid given by the equation $ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1 $ with $a,b,c > 0$ , let $(x,y,z) \in K$ on the first octant, consider the parallelepiped of vertices $(\pm x,\pm y,\pm z)$ inscribed on $K$  with volume $V = 8xyz$.

How can I find the maximum possible value of $V$?

I stuck with this hard problem for me i tried to find the explicit equation and then get the maximum values : Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be a point on the ellipsoid with $x,y,z\gt 0$.Then i took the eight different points with $P_i (\pm x,\pm y,\pm z)$  the vertices of a parallelepiped with the side length $2x , 2y$ and $2z$.

Then, the volume parallelepiped is $V = 2x\cdot 2y\cdot 2z = 8 xyz$ and i remembered that **$V$ is maximum if and only if $V^2$ is maximum** .

Some help please.

Comment: Do you know the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: yes i tried put $L(x,y,z, \lambda) = 8 xyz + \lambda( \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} - 1 ) $ is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, then if you proceeded with that, where did you get stuck?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324422/dimensions-of-a-box-of-maximum-volume-inside-an-ellipsoid

Comment: Why is the volume $V=8xyz$ instead of only $V=xyz$???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

We have

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}\frac{y^2}{b^2}\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)^{1/3} \le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right) = \frac{1}{3}$$

Thus
$$V=8|xyz| \le \frac{8abc}{\sqrt{27}}$$

Comment: why you get
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}\frac{y^2}{b^2}\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)^{1/3} \le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right) $$
 ?

Comment: geometric mean $\le$ arithmetic mean, like $(a+b)/2 \ge \sqrt{ab}$