# Maxima-Minima with multivariable function.

Tags: optimization

Let's have:
$$f(x,y)=\max\{x^2+2y,y^2+4x\}\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$$
We need to find the least value of $f(x+y)$, Now let us choose $*$ to denote any of $\ge,\le,=,<,>$.
Here:
$$x^2+2y*y^2+4x\implies \frac{(x-2)^2}{\sqrt3^2}-\frac{(y-1)^2}{\sqrt3^2}*0$$
which denotes regions of a hyperbola with centre at $2,1$. I do not get what can we do next.

Comment: I have seen multivariable maxima and minima, usually have an extra constraint set up usually a path associated. For e.g, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277607/global-maximum-and-minimum-of-fx-y-z-xyz-with-the-constraint-x22y23z2#comment2594511_1277607 , probably try take the gradient and see if anything helps :/

Comment: @Mann no Lagarnage multipliers.