# maximum volume of a box inside an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, volume

> What is the maximum volume of a box that can be placed inside an ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{25}=1$

The volume of a box is $V=xyz$ so I need to find $x,y,z$ with respect to the ellipsoid conditions and then find the maximum point.

$x=\sqrt{16-\frac{16y^2}{9}-\frac{16z^2}{25}}$

$y=\sqrt{9-\frac{9x^2}{16}-\frac{9z^2}{25}}$

$z=\sqrt{25-\frac{25x^2}{16}-\frac{25y^2}{9}}$

We take only the positive root as the length but on the other hand a negative root is just a length to the other direction and if 2 of the variables are negative the volume will be still a positive number

Comment: Looks like a job for Lagrange multipliers. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just a sec, I have no info in the box so its volume is $xyz$.

Comment: @amd I tried to find z and find the maximum point

Comment: You’re assuming that the sides of the inscribed box are parallel to the coordinate axes. That’s not explicitly stated in your question. With that assumption, $xyz$ is only the volume of the part of the box in the 1st octant.

Comment: Anyway, your approach will work. If you know about Lagrange multipliers (as described in Matthias’ answer), try that instead as the computations involved will be much simpler.

Comment: @amd so should o take both positive and negative roots? For x,y,z?

Comment: See what they are first. By symmetry, I’d expect them to come in $\pm$ pairs.

Comment: If you look at the related question (in the sidebar), you can find some similar questions, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129249/maximize-volume-of-box-in-ellipsoid) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324422/dimensions-of-a-box-of-maximum-volume-inside-an-ellipsoid).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I looked at them but all of them use Lagrange multipliers

Comment: @gbox Not true. There are some answers based on AM-GM inequality. (And I am not sure what is wrong with using Lagrange multipliers.)

Answer (score 1):

One simple standard procedure would be when you have the condition:

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{25}=1$$

and you want to maximize

$$V(x,y,z)=xyz$$

to set $$\vec\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda\cdot\vec\nabla V(x,y,z)$$

their gradient looking in the same direction. After that you have to choose the maxima out of the extrema.

This is the geometric approach learned in my analyses course.

Comment: Why should I take $V=8xyz$ and not $V=xyz$?

Comment: @gbox I was not sure. That's why the eight was in brackets ;)